# Can two devices running the same PWA detect proximity to each other?

Tags: android, geolocation, progressive-web-apps

I'm experimenting with writing a simple game as a PWA and wanted to provide the users a way to find each other. In my ideal world it would function like StreetPass on the 3DS but I'm not sure if:

1. That's something mobile devices are capable of
2. If that's something that can be done in a PWA

It's certainly not ideal (and probably not something that would work in production) but I suspect I'm going to have to instead request access to geolocation data, send that data occasionally (very occasionally) to a backend, and compare the proximity of the other devices doing the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Geolocation API](https://whatwebcando.today/geolocation.html) is the best bet you have for any location needs using PWA. It obviously comes with its own disadvantages like getting GeoLocation in shady/indoor location is not accurate, slow and resource intensive. But if your usecase is fine with not-so-precise location, then this API would do as its support is available in all major browsers.

Comment: Yeah, after reading up on it a bit I realized this wasn't possible since all a PWA has access to is what the browser does.